# Passing a function as a prop in Vue js to fetch data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, storybook

I have a component that I would like to be decoupled from the fetching data implementation. So that I can pass fetching data callback as a prop.

I would like to do that so that I can mock the fetching data in storybook.

Request.js

```
export const endpoints = {
  fetchProducts: page => `https://some-end-point-here?page=${page}`
};

export const fetchProducts = async (page = 1, endpoint = endpoints.fetchProducts(1)) => {
  const response = await fetch(endpoint);
  return await response.json();
};
```

(storybook) Where component is being used

```
import {fetchProducts} from "./request";
export const someCPM = ()=> ({
    components: {SomeCPM},
    props: {
        fetchProducts: {default: fetchProducts},
    },
    template: `<product-grid v-bind="$props"></product-grid>`
});
```

Prop type of component

```
  fetchProducts: {
    type: Function,
    required: true
  }
```

Problem is that I keep getting warned about the wrong prop type. Meaning it is getting Promise.
Thus failing to execute as fetch products is not a function.

Even if a make fetchProducts to return number and remove async nature, like this:

```
const fetchProducts = () => 9999
```

I am then getting that fetch product is a number, not a function!
This means that even tho I am passing a **reference** to the function somewhere somehow it is being executed.

Comment: you haven't shown (I don't think) how you're passing a function in a prop .. e.g. `<some-component someprop="somethingYouArePassing" />`

Comment: @JaromandaX I did, you can see in storybook.
using v-bind="$props", same happens if I pass prop directly as :fetchProducts

Comment: I think vue sees the prop is a function, so executes it ... perhaps if the function were a function that returns a function ... `() => () => { code here }`?

Comment: or ... `:fetchProps="this.fetchProps"` - based on https://medium.com/@jariwalamahek/how-to-pass-function-as-a-prop-in-vue-b7b0040260ba

Comment: @JaromandaX yes! making a factory function make it work. But I do not like it :)
Is there a way not to do it like that?
:fetchProps="this.fetchProps" this doesn't work for some reason...

Comment: `Is there a way not to do it like that?` - not that I've found - but [passing functions in props in vuejs is an anti-pattern](https://medium.com/js-dojo/passing-functions-as-props-an-anti-pattern-in-vue-js-b542fc0cf5d) so, I've never needed to do it, so ...

Comment: @JaromandaX I have seen that articles. But as you can see I am only passing the request method that will return the data. Component state is still being change from within the parent component and it is only changing its own state.

I can not find any article saying that callbacks are not always anti pattern...
Does this approach make sense to you?

Comment: @JaromandaX because I am not passing a callback to the child in order to change the parent data. I am not doing that. That it an antipattern for sure, and would always use event for such cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use factory function to make it work.

```
export const fetchProducts = () => async (page = 1, endpoint = endpoints.fetchProducts(1)) => {
  const response = await fetch(endpoint);
  return await response.json();
};
```